Как скрыть все коммиты до последнего
Есть проект который я разрабатывал приватно и там много раз мелькал приватный токен в коммитах, теперь этого всего в проекте нет, но по старым коммитам найти можно.

Можно создать новую ветку и в нее перенести последний коммит, удалив старую ветку, вроде что-то подобное можно провернуть с помощью git rebase. Просто никогда с таким не сталкивался, всегда приват данные храню в локальных конфигах

Поменять токен не судьба?

Токен уже скомпрометирован. Есть возможность выкачать всю историю репозитория локально, отредактировать её как угодно и затем заместить на сервере новой историей. Я проделывал подобное с репозиторием, в который попали "нежелательные" почтовые адреса. Но ещё раз, токен уже скомпрометирован. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History
